# Ordering of tasks in a gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to implement very simple chain of tasks in my project by Gulp:

1. Copy all files;
2. Replace some placeholders with values;
3. Minify some
   files;

And for these purposes I have created gulpfile with such main task:

```
gulp.task(tasks.build, [
          tasks.simplyCopy, 
          tasks.minifyXml, 
          tasks.minifyJs, 
          tasks.subst]);
```

It's a pretty simple and self describable.

Below I wrote full gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp');
var prettyData = require('gulp-pretty-data');
var uglify     = require('gulp-uglify');
var renvy      = require('gulp-renvy');

var tasks = {
    simplyCopy: "simply-copy",
    minifyXml:  "minify-xml",
    minifyJs:   "minify-js",
    subst:      "renvy-subst",
    build:      "build"
};

// Collection of tasks
gulp.task(tasks.build, [tasks.simplyCopy, tasks.minifyXml, tasks.minifyJs, 
tasks.subst]);

// By this task sources simply copy to the destination
var destination = 'dist/';
gulp.task(tasks.simplyCopy, function () {
    gulp.src(['Source/**/*.*', '!Source/www/res/strings/*.*'], {base: 
'Source/www'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});

var stringsDestPath = 'dist/res/strings/';
var stringSrcPath   = 'Source/www/res/strings/';

// By this task some xml files minify
gulp.task(tasks.minifyXml, [tasks.simplyCopy], function() {
    gulp.src(stringSrcPath + '*.xml')
        .pipe(prettyData({
            type: 'minify',
            preserveComments: true,
            extensions: {
                'xlf': 'xml',
                'svg': 'xml'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stringsDestPath))
});

var placeholder = {
    '%version%': {'prod':'010.00',   'dev':'010.00'}
};


// By this task in some files placeholders replaces with value
gulp.task(tasks.subst, [tasks.minifyXml, tasks.minifyJs], function(){
    return gulp.src(stringsDestPath + '*.*')
        .pipe(renvy(placeholder, 'dev'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stringsDestPath));
});


// By this task some js files minify 
gulp.task(tasks.minifyJs, [tasks.simplyCopy], function () {
    gulp.src(stringSrcPath + '*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stringsDestPath))
});
```

But I have such unexpected behavior:

replacing of placeholders is not happening, but it's executes.

```
[16:29:51] Using gulpfile C:\PDDirectory\Workspace\src\some_workbench\User_Part\gulpfile.js
[16:29:51] Starting 'simply-copy'...
[16:29:51] Finished 'simply-copy' after 17 ms
[16:29:51] Starting 'minify-xml'...
[16:29:51] Finished 'minify-xml' after 7.49 ms
[16:29:51] Starting 'minify-js'...
[16:29:51] Finished 'minify-js' after 5.84 ms
[16:29:51] Starting 'renvy-subst'...
[16:29:51] Finished 'renvy-subst' after 28 ms
[16:29:51] Starting 'build'...
[16:29:51] Finished 'build' after 5.66 ?s
```

Task `tasks.subst` executed sepparetly works fine, but in a chain with other tasks, I see results of executing copy and minify only.
Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `tasks.subst` has the sole dependency for `tasks.build`

```
gulp.task(tasks.build, [tasks.subst]);
```

Since `tasks.subst` requires all the others, the ordering should be correct and adding all the other tasks may lead to ordering problems.

From the [`gulp.task` documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/62323fc55dd080a58ed030c5e9df176bdf551eae/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps--fn):

> **Note:** Are your tasks running before the dependencies are complete?
>   Make sure your dependency tasks are correctly using the async run
>   hints: take in **a callback or return a promise or event stream**.

To ensure that a task dependencies are fulfilled before executing it, Gulp needs each task to return a [stream](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options) or a promise, or call the [task function `callback` parameter](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#accept-a-callback).

In your case, the following task should just `return` the stream:

- `tasks.minifyXml`
- `tasks.minifyJs`
- `tasks.simplyCopy`

For example:

```
gulp.task(tasks.minifyXml, [tasks.simplyCopy], function(done) {
    // just return the task stream here
    return gulp.src(stringSrcPath + '*.xml')
        .pipe(prettyData({
            // ...
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stringsDestPath));
});
```

or using the callback when it's not possible to return a stream:

```
gulp.task('somename', function(done) {

  // async function which does not return a stream like other gulp functions
  getFilesAsync(function(err, res) {
    // pass any errors to the callback
    if (err) return done(err);

    var stream = gulp.src(res)
      .pipe(minify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      .on('end', done); // use the callback when it's done
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to place `task.subst` singly, it doesn't work, unfortunately. In this case, I have the same log of tasks executing, but and result I have the same.

Comment: @PavelPraulov When I skimmed over your question, I had seen that `tasks.subst` was correctly returning the stream and assumed the other tasks were as well. I updated my answer with additional information on async tasks ordering.

Comment: Now it's works. Thanks you, for your attention, knowledges and fast answers.